# How can I see what I am typing in telnet?

Tags: telnet

When using telnet by using the command:

```
telnet <host ip> <port>
```

I can connect but then I cannot see what I am typing.

So I try:

```
telnet
set localecho
open <host ip> <port>
```

But this time it just hangs with the message:

```
Connecting to <host ip>...
```

How can I use telnet successfully after setting localecho?

Comment: the above works fine for me on Windows 7. What o/s are you using? Also are you sure you get "Connected" when you try without the set localecho portion?

Comment: Windows 7. Yep pretty sure, I imediately get a blank screen and if I type some garbage I get a http 'invalid verb' response.

Comment: so on windows 7 after you type "set localecho" it should print "local echo on or off" what does it say for you?

Comment: It was working after all I just didn't realise :S thanks.

Comment: @casperOne Why was this closed? The faq says: "question generally covers" ... "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: @lockstock Addressing the second part ("practical, answerable"), that's the bar for *all* questions on *all* Stack Exchange sites, this is not in question.  As for the first part, there's nothing tying it to a programming issue here (and that's important, as it's used for more than just programming tasks) and this is slightly more on topic as is on Super User.  Most questions about telnet on Stack Overflow are about telnet as a protocol.  Additionally, there were two flags on the post as "off topic" prompting the look at the post to begin with.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It actually isn't hanging; it's just that, for some reason, it doesn't give any feedback to show that it's connected. If you start typing, you'll see that your input shows up in the upper-left hand corner of the window, overwriting what's already there. For example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1rosoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> open example.com 80
Connecting To example.com...
```

You can see that I've typed `GET / HTTP/1.1`, overwriting `Welcome to Mic`.

(By the way, notice that I didn't have to type `set localecho`: for me local-echo was already on when I launched `telnet` without arguments, and I'm betting that for you it's the same.)