# Cannot see what I am typing in telnet

Tags: windows-7, cmd, telnet

I enabled telnet in widows 7 and when I type in CMD: telnet www.example.com 80 the screen clears and then I cannot see what I am typing. Although I can trace the cursor which moves with every character typed.
I saw this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874493/how-can-i-see-what-i-am-typing-in-telnet)  which was the most relevant. However, when I type GET / HTTP/1.0 nothing happens and when I press ctrl+] it does not accept GET / HTTP/1.0. What should I do to see the page?

Comment: it's a windows specific thing, you can use putty for telnet in windows

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
telnet
set localecho
open <host ip> <port>
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874493/how-can-i-see-what-i-am-typing-in-telnet)

Answer (score 1):

It generally works but type your text without editing, no errors, and press enter to send it.

There is a scriptable telnet client you can download for free:

**Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0**
**by Albert Yale ay@aci.qc.ca**

Answer (score 1):

For the problem that you cannot see what you are typing, I guess it's just the way Windows telnet client is designed.
I tried using telnet in Linux, no this problem.
If you are using Windows 10, you can try installing the Linux sub system, and then use telnet in the Linux subsystem.